# Subqueries in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, subquery, conventions, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

I have two tables `products` and `product_categories` that are associated through a third table, `products_categories_products`, according to CakePHP BelongsToMany conventions (Edit: these associations are established in `ProductsTable.php` and `ProductCategoriesTable.php`). I want to generate a list of product categories, using the image from the best selling products to represent each category.

I can achieve my desired outcome using the following function:

```
public function findImages(Query $query, array $options) {
    $query->select([
        'ProductCategories.id',
        'ProductCategories.name',
        'ProductCategories__image' => '(SELECT Products.image
        FROM product_categories_products AS ProductCategoriesProducts
        LEFT JOIN products AS Products
        ON ProductCategoriesProducts.product_id = Products.id
        WHERE ProductCategoriesProducts.product_category_id = ProductCategories.id
        ORDER BY Products.turnover DESC
        LIMIT 1)'
    ])->where([
        'ProductCategories.name <>' => 'Unsorted'
    ])->order([
        'ProductCategories.name'    => 'asc'
    ]);
    return $query;
}
```

Is this acceptable or is there a Cake-ier way to achieve my goal? I couldn't really find anything on the topic of crafting subqueries in CakePHP 3. I just stumbled into the above solution after a couple hours of frustration. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Have you made the correct associations in the model? If so, what could you edit the question to state what you have?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris! I've edited my question to reflect the location of the model associations.

Comment: I meant can you post the actual code so that we can see what the actual associations are

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353433/cakephp-3-not-in-query/33372036#33372036

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the link from user ndm_yesterday, I generated the following solution:

```
public function findImages(Query $query, array $options) {
    $this->hasMany('ProductCategoriesProducts');

    $subquery = $this->ProductCategoriesProducts->find('all')->select([
        'Products.image'
    ])->join([
        [
            'table'     => 'products',
            'alias'     => 'Products',
            'type'      => 'LEFT',
            'conditions'=> [
                'ProductCategoriesProducts.product_id = Products.id'
            ]
        ]
    ])->where([
        'ProductCategoriesProducts.product_category_id = ProductCategories.id'
    ])->order([
        'Products.turnover' => 'DESC'
    ])->limit(1);

    $query->select([
        'ProductCategories.id',
        'ProductCategories.name',
        'ProductCategories__image' => $subquery
    ])->where([
        'ProductCategories.name <>' => 'Unsorted'
    ])->order([
        'ProductCategories.name'    => 'asc'
    ]);

    return $query;
}
```