# how to use "where in query" cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp

i have use mysql query:

```
SELECT doctor_id FROM `appointments`where doctor_id in (SELECT doctor_id FROM doctor_staffs WHERE staff_id=11)
```

> Result:

```
doctor_id
2
4
5
```

but I need to know how to write it in CakePHP 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subqueries in CakePHP 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884603/subqueries-in-cakephp-3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $this->loadModel('DoctorStaffs');
    $docTorStaff=$this->DoctorStaffs->find()->select(['doctor_id'])->where(['staff_id'=>11]);
    $this->loadModel('Appointments');
    $appointments = $this->Appointments->find();
    $appointments=$appointments->where(['Appointments.doctor_id IN'=>$docTorStaff]);
```